# Angular binding variable not being set from $http scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, post, angularjs-directive

Im new to angular and I'm trying to create a simple Signup Form which posts to a database (in json).

If the database write is successful, "this.msg" is set to "Post Data Submitted Successfully!"

If the database write is unsuccessful, "this.msg" is set to "Service does not Exists"

```
<row ng-controller="appController as app">
    <div>
        Username : <input ng-model="app.regUsername" /> 
        Password : <input ng-model="app.regPassword" />         
        <input type="button" value="Register" ng-click="app.postdata(app.regUsername, app.regPassword)" /> 
    </div>
        <p>Output Message :{{app.msg}}</p>
</row>
```

However I cant get this.msg to print out in my HTML. Everything seems to be working fine, no console errors, this.msg exists, the database write is ok.

```
app.controller('appController', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.name = null;
    this.password = null;

this.postdata = function (name, password) {

    var data = {
        name: name,
        password: password
    };

    $http.post('https://my-project.com/.json', JSON.stringify(data)).then(function (response) {
        if (response.data){
            this.msg = "Post Data Submitted Successfully!";
            console.log(this.msg) //works fine;
        }
    }, function (response) {
            this.msg = "Service does not Exists";
            console.log(this.msg) //works fine
    });
};
```

All I can presume is that there is a scope issue and {{app.msg}} is somehow outside of this scope

Comment: it's all about the scope, `this` changes the scope everytime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign scope to another variable, `this` is executed with the context of `post()`

Try this

```
app.controller('appController', ['$http', function ($http) {
    self = this; // <-- add this
    self.name = null;
    self.password = null;

    self.postdata = function (name, password) {

        var data = {
            name: name,
            password: password
        };

        $http.post('https://my-project.com/.json', 
              JSON.stringify(data)).then(function (response) {
            if (response.data){
                self.msg = "Post Data Submitted Successfully!";
                console.log(self.msg) //works fine;
            }
        }, function (response) {
                self.msg = "Service does not Exists";
                console.log(self.msg) //works fine
        });
    };
```

Comment: is "self" a type of keyword? how do i access this from my html ? would it be app.self.username?

Comment: No, it would be `app.username`, there should not be any change inside the template :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
app.controller('appController', ['$http', function ($http) {
  this.name = null;
  this.password = null;
  var appCtrl = this;

  this.postdata = function (name, password) {

    var data = {
      name: name,
      password: password
    };

    $http.post('https://my-project.com/.json', JSON.stringify(data)).then(function (response) {
      if (response.data) {
        appCtrl.msg = "Post Data Submitted Successfully!";
        console.log(appCtrl.msg) //works fine;
      }
    }, function (response) {
      appCtrl.msg = "Service does not Exists";
      console.log(appCtrl.msg) //works fine
    });
  };
```